# why string, array and dictionary in Swift changed to value type

Tags: objective-c, swift, value-type, reference-type

In Objc string, array and dictionary are all reference types, while in Swift they are all value types.

1. I want to figure out what's the reason behind the scenes, for my understanding, no matter it is a reference type or value type, the objects live in the heap in both Objc and Swift.
2. Was the change for making coding easier? i.e. if it is reference type then the pointer to the object might not be nil, so need to check both pointer and the object not nil for accessing the object. While if it is value type then only need to check the object itself?
3. But in terms of memory allocation, value types and reference types are same, right? both allocated same size of memory?

thanks

Comment: It's discussed in [this Swift blog](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10).  It's basically to make multi-threaded programs harder to break.  Poor decision in my opinion.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Arrays, dictionaries etc. in Objective-C are often mutable. That means when I pass an array to another method, and then that array is modified behind the back of the other method, surprising (to put it gently) behaviour will happen.

By making arrays, dictionaries etc. value types, this surprising behaviour is avoided. When you receive a Swift array, you know that nobody is going to modify it behind your back. Objects that can be modified behind your back are a major source for problems.

In reality, the Swift compiler tries to avoid unnecessary copying whenever possible. So even if it says that an array is officially copied, it doesn't mean that it is *really* copied.

Comment: I have never trapped in that major source of problems. However, how deep is the copy of the array? And why is it a "major source of problems", when the array changes, but no "major source of problems", when an item in that array changed one of its properties? And why did they think at the Swift team that the change of an item is no "major source of problems" while changing the length of the array is a "major source of problems" for a long time and why did they change their opinion?

Comment: I agree with you mostly, but I guess, in Obj-C it is the developers responsibility not to pass/request mutable objects as long as there is no other choice. the non-mutable objects cannot be modified behind the caller's back, so from this perspective your logic looks a kinda broken to me.

Comment: My point of logic is simply that "modifying behind my back" does not cause serious problems in practice. It is one of Swift's "we solve a problem that does only theoretically exists" features. Did you have that problem in production code only once? So at the beginning there was a quick & dirty (inconsistent) solution for a no-problem and now we have a consistent solution for a no-problem that makes thinks sometimes more difficult and will have a performance print.

Comment: For anyone interested, the reason they solved this "no-problem" even though you haven't run into it yourself *might be* that others (framework developers) have put in a lot of work to protect you from these errors where they are most likely to occur. That's the impression I got from watching "Building Better Apps with Value Types in Swift" from WWDC15.

Comment: @gnasher729 `if it says that an array is officially copied, it doesn't mean that it is really copied` . Can you pls provide a reference for it?

Comment: @SandeepAggarwal https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-ID82     last topic "Assignment and copy..." see the Note

Comment: It has copy-on-write. Hence the “it isn’t really copied”.

Comment: Hope this may save someone's minute, this is from the docs: "Collections defined by the standard library like arrays, dictionaries, and strings use an optimization to reduce the performance cost of copying. Instead of making a copy immediately, these collections share the memory where the elements are stored between the original instance and any copies. If one of the copies of the collection is modified, the elements are copied just before the modification. The behavior you see in your code is always as if a copy took place immediately"

Comment: I have to disagree with the initial statement in this answer: _Arrays, dictionaries etc. in Objective-C are often mutable. That means when I pass an array to another method, and then that array is modified behind the back_. In that case you should be defining the array/dictionary parameter using the non-mutable type, and _upcasting_ your mutable instance when you pass it.  This works because the mutable type is a subclass of the non-mutable type and it will avoid such behaviour.

Answer (score 7):

The Swift team is very active on the official developer forums. So, I'm assuming that since you didn't ask there, you're more curious about the community's broader "sense" of what the change means, as opposed to the technical implementation details. If you want to understand exactly "why", just go ask them :)

The explanation that makes the most sense to me is that Objects should be responsible for reacting to, and updating the state of your application. Values should be the state of your application. In other words, an Array or a String or a Dictionary (and other value types) should never be responsible for responding to user input or network input or error conditions, etc. The Objects handle that and store the resulting data into those values.

One cool feature in Swift, which makes a complex Value Type (like a Dictionary or a custom type like Person, as opposed to a simple Float) more viable, is that the value types can encapsulate rules and logic because they can have functions. If I write a value type `Person` as a struct, then the Person struct can have a function for updating a name due to marriage, etc. That's solely concerned with the data, and not with /managing/ the state. The Objects will still decide WHEN and WHY to updating a Person's name, but the business logic of how to go about doing so safely/test-ably can be included in the Value Type itself. Hence giving you a nice way to increase isolation and reduce complexity.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the previous answers, there are also multi-threading issues to consider with sharing a Reference-Based collection type that we don't have to worry as much with sharing an instance of a type that is Value-Based and has Copy-On-Write behavior.  Multi-core is becoming more and more proliferant even on iOS devices, so it has become more of an issue for the Swift language developers to consider.

Answer (score -7):

I do not know, whether this is the real idea behind it, but have a historical view on it:

At the beginning, an array copy behaved by reference, when you changed an item in it. It behaved by value, when you changed the length of the array. They did it for performance reasons (less array copy). But of course this was, eh, how can I express that politly, eh, difficult with Swift at all, eh, let's call it a "do not care about a good structure if you can win some performance, you probably never need" approach. Some called that copy-on-write, what is not much more intelligent, because COW is transparent, while that behavior was not transparent. Typical Swift wording: Use a buzzword, use it the way, it fits to Swift, don't care about correctness.

Later on arrays got a complete by copy behavior, what is less confusing. (You remember, Swift was for readability. Obviously in Swift's concept, readability means "less characters to read", but does not mean "better understandable". Typical Swift wording: Use a buzzword, use it the way, it fits to Swift, don't care about correctness. Did I already mention that?)

So, I guess it is still performance plus understandable behavior probably leading to less performance. (You will better know when a copy is needed in your code and you can still do that and you get a 0-operation from Cocoa, if the source array is immutable.) Of course, they could say: "Okay, by value was a mistake, we changed that." But they will never say.

However, now arrays in Swift behave consistently. A big progress in Swift! Maybe you can call it a programming language one sunny day.

Comment: That doesn't answer any of the questions asked. That's just your opinion on Swift in general.